# Objects shift on screen when one is removed

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist, gameobject

I am making an android app, and right now whenever an object moves off screen and is removed from the ArrayList, all the objects of the same type are shifted to the right.

Ex: A box(We will call this boxOne) spawns on the right hand side of the screen (As do other boxes). When boxOne moves far enough off the screen to the left hand side, it is removed. When boxOne is removed from the ArrayList all of the other boxes shift themselves to the right several pixels.

```
if(boxElapsed > 3000){
            boxs.add(new Box(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lightbox),
                    (WIDTH+10), boxHeight, 44, 44, player.getScore(), 1));
            boxStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < boxs.size(); i++){
            boxs.get(i).update();
            if(collision(boxs.get(i), player)){
                if(powerShieldActive == true){
                    boxs.remove(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    player.setPlaying(false);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(boxs.get(i).getX() < 0-32){
                boxs.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: any xml code ??

Comment: No, the only xml there is is for my home screen prior to starting the game.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why do the objects shift when one is removed